# I am not getting desired o/p for this

Tags: c, string, getchar

i want to replace the `newline` by `\n` in a string and i am unable to do this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
void escape(char x[],char  y[]);
main()
{
int c=0,i;
char s[MAX],t[MAX];
for(i=0; (c=getchar())!=EOF && i<MAX;i++)
 s[i]=c;

s[i]='\0';
for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
 printf("%c",s[k]);

escape(s,t); 
}

void escape(char x[],char y[])
{
int j=0,m=0;
while(x[j]!='\0')
 {
    if (x[j]=='\n')
    {
      y[m++] = '\\';
      y[m] = 'n';   
     }
    y[m]=x[j]; 
    j++; 
    m++;   
 }
 y[m]='\0';
 for(int k=0;y[k]!='\0';k++)
 printf("%c",y[k]);  
}
```

the o/p i get is:

my name is amol

^Z

my name is amol

my name is amol\

Comment: You are writing "\n" but then immediately overwriting the n with a newline. You need to skip `y[m]=x[j];` in the case of the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out an `else` in the `escape()` function, hence the `'n'` is being overwritten

```
if (x[j]=='\n')
{
    y[m++] = '\\';
    y[m] = 'n';   
}
else            // <<<--- added a line
    y[m]=x[j];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here It self you can simply add that

```
  for(i=0; (c=getchar())!=EOF && i<MAX;i++){
       if(c=='\n'){
          s[i++]='\\';
          s[i]='n';
       }
       else
         s[i]=c;
     }
```

After Adding you `\ and n` on your code you need to `conitnue` the loop from 
starting (or), remaining blocks you need to add on the `else` part